# How to save an uploaded file to the database instead of the name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails3 and have created a simple document table with a document_name (string) and document (blob) column and a few other columns for metadata. I've added

```
<%= f.label :document %><br />
<%= f.file_field :document %>
```

to the _form.html.erb partial. The model is unchanged (generated via rails g scaffold...)

Update and New actions works fine for all columns but the uploaded document is not saved into the document column. Instead, the name of the uploaded document is saved to the document column (not the file content).

How can I write the uploaded binary data to the document field and the uploaded file name to the document_name column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you forgot to set `:multipart=>true` in the form tag.

Could you post the whole "new" form?

Comment: Uhh, right. I've changed it to form_for(@admin_article, :html => {:multipart=>true}) and added a custom accessor for the document column which splits the filename and data to the fields.

Answer (score 0):

This is called upload. You can do it from scratch (Rails offers a pretty good support for uploading) or use one of the following Rails plugins:

- [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)
- [CarrierWave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave)

Answer (score 0):

Here the part of the form for file creation and editing. Ignore the obvious custom functions.

```
<%=form_for  fs_object,:url=>(fs_object.id ? fs_object_path( fs_object) : fs_objects_path),:html=>{:multipart=>true} do |f|%>
        <%=p.prop_capture :image do %>
            <%FsFile.images.each do |i|%>
                <%=  f.radio_button(:image, i)%><%=image_tag i,:height=>50%>
            <%end%>
        <%end%> 
    <%=p.prop "file upload",f.file_field(:content_binary)%>
    <%=link_to "download",download_fs_object_url(@object,:action=>"download"),:remote=>@js,:method=>:post if @object.id%>
    <%=p.prop :content_type %>
<%end%>
```

This is the controller create action to create a file or a folder.
The binary content of the file is managed by **handle_content**.

```
def create
        p=params[:fs_folder]||params[:fs_file]
        @object =if params[:fs_folder]
          FsFolder.new(p)
        elsif params[:fs_file]
          FsFile.handle_content p
          h=FsFile.new(p)
        end
    end
```

The handle content, what manages the binary content and the content type in the FSFile.

```
   def handle_content p
        if(p)
          if p[:content_binary]
            p=self.class.handle_content(p)
            if !p[:content_ending]
              p[:content_ending]=content_ending
            end
          end   
        end
        p
      end
       def self.handle_content p
        if(p)
          if p[:content_binary]
            logger.info "UPLOADED: #{p[:content_binary]}"
            c=p[:content_binary].read
            ext=File.extname p[:content_binary].original_filename
            p[:content_ending]=ext
            type=File.mime_type? p[:content_binary].original_filename
            debug "'#{p[:content_binary].original_filename}' '#{p[:name]}'"
            p[:name]=p[:content_binary].original_filename if !p[:name]||p[:name].strip==""
            #        type=ext.match(/od./) ? "Open Document file" : type
            p[:content_type]=type
    #        p[:image]=get_image_for_type p[:content_type] if !p[:image]
            p[:content_binary]=c

          end
        end
        p
      end
```

In my gemfile i added for the MIME types:

```
gem 'mimetype-fu'
```

I hope that helped.